# Добавление элемента в tree control

Tags: c++, mfc, treeview

В *tree control* можно добавлять *item*, который содержит в себе текст

```
hTree = treeObject->InsertItem(L"All object", TVI_ROOT);
```

Также у меня есть указатель на объект моего класса.

Могу ли я при добавлении *item* в *tree* каким-либо образом привязать этот указатель к *item*, чтобы можно было впоследствии по нажатию на *item* получать доступ к этому указателю?

Comment: MFC страшно устарел. Если вы учитесь или разрабатываете новый проект, подумайте о другом фреймворке для пользовательского интерфейса. Наример, о Qt.

Comment: Это правда. Только у меня задание использовать wfc. Если бы не было этого ограничения было бы проще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете достигнуть желаемого, воспользовавшись вот этим методом:

```
HTREEITEM InsertItem( 
UINT nMask, 
LPCTSTR lpszItem, 
int nImage, 
int nSelectedImage, 
UINT nState, 
UINT nStateMask, 
LPARAM lParam, 
HTREEITEM hParent, 
HTREEITEM hInsertAfter);
```

Нужный указатель на экземпляр класса можно передать, затолкав его в LPARAM (static_cast<>() вам в помощь). Могут быть глюки с разрядностью - дока MSDN говорит, что LPARAM 32 битный.

Получить значение потом можно будет методом

```
CTreeCtrl::GetItemData()
```

Скастовать его обратно в указатель на свой класс (для пущей надежности, можно пожертвовать скоростью и применить dynamic_cast<>())

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я нашёл ещё способ  с помощью SetItemData

Comment: @ВалентинЧикунов А это абсолютно то же самое, выставляется тот же параметр. Только на один вызов больше придется делать.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Вы правы, просто первое на что я натолкнулся было SetItemData. Ещё раз спасибо за помощь